# SignalR and Windows Authentication

Tags: signalr, windows-authentication, signalr-hub

I'm trying to use SignalR with Windows authentication but I canget it to work. If I set site access to deny anonymous users the HTML page loads but signalr/hubs fails to load. If I set the Authorize attribute on the Hub class the server methods never get called.

What I want to do in the end is have the server execute code with the client users Active Directory credentials.